# parsing html data in android

Tags: android

I am making an application in which i have to parse HTML data. I have got data that i want. But data is repeating five to six times. I m saving data into string, but when i am printing this string there is no repeated data. e.g data having 23 values and it is repeating five or six times. I have entered static string it is displaying fine.
Here is code:

```
doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://altoona.craigslist.org/search/cta?query=Ford+WINDSTAR&srchType=T&minAsk=&maxAsk=").get();
System.out.println("*****DOC*****"+doc);
s1=doc.getAllElements().text().toString();
System.out.println("**************S1*************"+s1);
```

Please help me where m doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try this one http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

HTML Parser is a Java library used to parse HTML in either a linear or nested fashion. Primarily used for transformation or extraction, it features filters, visitors, custom tags and easy to use JavaBeans. It is a fast, robust and well tested package.